# Help with optimizing some functioning jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have some simple jQuery that adds some tab functionality. This is based on something I found somewhere (can't recall where), but it's probably mostly original at this point. I was having trouble with some selectors, so I had to do some stuff that seemed awkward (see the .children().children part). The awkward parts stem from adding the ability to handle multiple sets of tabs on a single page.

Am I possibly using the selector wrong? And can you see any other room for improvement here?

Here's the jQuery:

```
// Create and manage tab blocks
$('.tab-sections section').hide(); // Hide all tabs
$('.tab-list').each(function(){ // Make the first tab active
    $('.tab-list li:first-child').addClass('active');
});
$('.tab-sections').each(function(){ // Make the first tab's content visible
    $('.tab-sections section:first-child').show();
});
$('.tab-list li').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active'); // Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass('active'); // Add "active" class to selected tab
    // Hide tabs. This looks awkward, but .children('.tab-sections section') wouldn't work
    $(this).parents('.tab-block').children('.tab-sections').children('section').hide();
    // Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    var activeTab = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    $(activeTab).fadeIn('fast'); // Fade in the active ID content
    return false;
});
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="tab-block grad-tabs">
 <ul class="tab-list">
     <li><a href="#tab1" title="tab 1">Tab 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab2" title="tab 2">Tab 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="tab3" title="tab 3">Tab 3</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div class="tab-sections">
     <section id="tab1">
      <h2>Tab 1</h2>
      <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
     </section>
     <section id="tab2">
      <h2>Tab 2</h2>
      <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
     </section>
     <section id="tab3">
      <h2>Tab 3</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
     </section>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a few more improvements, for your main question, you can use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to solve the [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) problem, instead of this:

```
$(this).parents('.tab-block').children('.tab-sections').children('section').hide();
```

Go up to the `.tab-block` using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) then [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) what you want inside, like this:

```
$(this).closest('.tab-block').find('.tab-sections section').hide();
```

For the rest, yes there are more optimizations, there's no need for the initial [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loops since they all do the same thing repeatedly and you can further optimize your initial hiding and chaining inside the [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler, like this:

```
$('.tab-sections section:not(:first-child)').hide(); // Hide all content that not the first
$('.tab-list li:first-child').addClass('active');
$('.tab-list li').click(function() {
   $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active'); // Add "active" class to selected tab, remove any other "active" class
   $(this).closest('.tab-block').find('.tab-sections section').hide(); // Hide tabs.
   var activeTab = $(this).find('a').attr('href'); // Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
   $(activeTab).fadeIn('fast');                    // Fade in the active ID content
   return false;
});
```

If you're on jQuery 1.4.1+ you can even further optimize this with [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), changing this:

```
$('.tab-list li').click(function() {
```

To this:

```
$('.tab-list').delegate('li', 'click', function() {
```

This attaches *one* `click` handler per `.tab-list` element, rather than one per `<li>`.

Answer (score 0):

You may interested in this

```
var sections = $('.tab-sections section');

sections.hide();

$('.tab-list li:first-child').addClass('active');

$('.tab-sections section:first-child').show();

$('.tab-list').delegate("li", "click", function() {

    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    sections.hide(); 

    var activeTab = $(this).children('a').attr('href'); 
    $(activeTab).fadeIn('fast');

});
```

Here I've cached the sections since it is used multiple times during the page actions.

Again the jquery [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method is used instead of adding 1 click event to each of the 3 `li` elements.

You can find a working sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZEqBR/), but I think you can have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZEqBR/3/) also.

Comment: This would break with multiple `.tab-sections` (or any other part) in the page, a concern the OP listed.

Comment: @Nick Then we can use the `$().data()` to cache the value